# Java error in one server but not in the other

Tags: java, unix

I have a function that uses waitFor as a part of processbuilder.

This is the specific line that uses it:

```
   if (pr.waitFor(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)) {
```

I am running this function in two unix servers that are more or less identical. It successfuly runs in one. However in the other, it gives me this error:

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.Process.waitFor(JLjava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;)Z
```

Both unix servers have identical Java -versions and permissions. What else could be lacking in one of the servers that is leading to this problem?

Comment: Is the `PATH` the same? ie, double-check the server is running the same Java JVM that you checked the    `-version` of ....

Comment: The path and the Java JVM are the same. I also tested an older version of the program where the only difference was the inclusion of waitFor and it runs successfully on both.

Comment: What is your JVM version? waitFor(long timeout,TimeUnit unit) is only from JDK 1.8.